# Using the CouchDB(1.6.1) List function to output to a csv file

Tags: csv, couchdb

I am trying to master the principles/syntax of using a list function in CouchDB 1.6.1 to output specific fields to a csv file.

I have set up a simple output to html and this seems easier to do and it works well.

What I want to do is have a view, which the list function requires, to output selected fields from the database and output the data to a csv file.

What I can't seem to be able to do is get the list function to 'read' the specific fields from the view output, which I succeded in doing to obtain html output.

The view function looks something like this:

```
function(doc){
emit({'A':doc.a, 'B':doc.b, 'C':doc.c.d  .....}, null);}
```

The html list function would look something like this:

```
"function(head, req){
start({'headers': {
'Content-Type': 'text/html' }});
send('<html><body><table>');
send('<tr><th>A</th><th>B</th><th>C</th></tr>');
while(row=getRow()){
send(''.concat( '<tr>', '<td>' + toJSON(row.key.A) + '</td>','<td>' + toJSON(row.key.B) + '</td>','<td>' + toJSON(row.key.C) + '</td>', '</tr>' ));}
send('</table></body></html>');}"
```

A similar list function for csv output for the same view should look like:

```
"function(head, req){
start({'headers': { 'Content-Type': 'text/csv' }});
send('A' +','+ 'B' +','+'C' + '\\n');
while(row=getRow()){
send(''.concat( toJSON(row.key.A)  , toJSON(row.key.B) ,  toJSON(row.key.C) ));};}"
```

this results in " `"error":"compilation_error","reason":"Expression does not eval to a function ...."`

I have tried numerous variations of the csv function without success except for a jumbled lot of incorrectly formatted text.

A recommended starting point for a csv list function was, on a certain website, given as:

```
function (head, req) {
start({

    “headers”: {

      “Content-Type”: “text/csv”

     }

  });

send(‘Username, Name, Email\n’);

while(row = getRow()) {

    send(row.value.username+’,’+row.value.email+’,’+row.value.metadata.name+’\n’);

  }

}
```

I cannot get this structure to work at all.

I would appreciate some input on the correct syntax to use please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find a guideline [here](https://www.slideshare.net/okurow/couchdb-list-and-show-introduction?qid=a1ce7d71-ceac-4a24-9dbd-e1dd881f56fc&v). A slideshare by Oliver Kurowski.

The basic principles are:

```
"views": {
"byPrice": {
"map": "function(doc){emit(doc.price, [doc.make,doc.year]);};"
}
}
"lists": { 
"csv": "function(head,req){start({'headers':{'Content-Type':'text/csv'}});send('Make'+','+'Year'+','+'Price'+'\\n');while(row=getRow()){send(row.value+','+row.key+'\\n');}};"
}
```

It worked fine.

Thank you Oliver.