# How to convert CouchDB into CSV files

Tags: php, database, csv, couchdb

I have CouchDB database in my local server, and the data are being updated in hourly bases.

how can I export data from CouchDB to CSV files?
what is the best practice to do this?

if there is no direct method to do this easily, I want to implement this using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look into the Couchdb List function:

[Using the CouchDB(1.6.1) List function to output to a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45011761/using-the-couchdb1-6-1-list-function-to-output-to-a-csv-file)

http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/transforming.html

Please be aware that the list function is proposed for deprecation in future Couchdb releases.
https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues/1534